# Error in code for logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, curve-fitting

I am writing the following script using PopulationGrowth.csv:

```
dat <-read.csv("/Path/PopulationGrowth.csv")
class = "data.frame", row.names=c(NA,-16L)
m1 <- nls(pop~SSlogis(Year,asym,xmid,scal),data=dat)
par(las=1,bty="l",mar=c(5,6,2,2)+0.1)  ## graphics tweaks
with(dat,plot(CentralOakland~Year,ylab=""))
mtext("Population",side=2,las=0,line=4)
yearvec <- 1940:2010
lines(yearvec,predict(m1,newdata=data.frame(Year=yearvec)))
```

After the last line I get the following error:

```
Error in predict(m1, newdata = data.frame(Year = yearvec)) : object 'm1' not found
```

Here is the data I am working with:

```
Year CentralOakland
1940 7852 
1950 8452
1960 6701
1970 6135
1980 5872
1990 5406
2000 5281
2010 6086
```

I also seek to forecast population trends over the next 30 years. There is reason to believe that population will be increasing over those next 30 years. What function is necessary to predict this?

Bear with me, I am new to R.

Comment: Shouldn't your regression formula be `CentralOakland ~ Year` (with the variable to predict on the left)?

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of little glitches here:

- you haven't given us a reproducible example: see e.g. http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ...
- you probably want `read.csv` rather than `read.table`
- I don't know what `quartz=(title...)` is doing.  Maybe `quartz(title=...)` ? In any case, using `plot()` should automatically open a new graphics window
- using `attach` is often a bad idea
- use `lines` rather than `curve` to add a new (e.g.) predicted data set to a plot. For the specific case of a linear regression (see next point), you can use `abline`.
- by far the most important: what you are doing here is **not** a logistic regression -- it's using `glm` to fit an ordinary linear model (least-squares regression), which can also be achieved more easily via `lm()`. Logistic regression would use `family=binomial` rather than `family=gaussian`. Furthermore, logistic regression is intended for binary response variables, so *it's unlikely to be appropriate for modeling the population of Central Oakland* ... I suspect you are confusing a logistic *regression* and a logistic *growth curve* ...

Here's some revised code:

```
dat <- read.csv("/Path/PopulationGrowth.csv")
with(dat,plot(Year,CentralOakland,xlab="Year",ylab="Population",
  main="Central Oakland Population vs. Year"))
g <- lm(CentralOakland~Year,data=dat)
abline(g)
## OR
yearvec <- seq(min(Year),max(Year),length=51)
lines(yearvec,predict(g,newdata=data.frame(Year=yearvec),type="response"))
```

On the other hand, maybe this is what you really wanted to do (you didn't give us data so I went to Wikipedia and got some ...)

```
## from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oakland,_California
dat <- structure(list(year = c(1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1900L, 1910L, 
1920L, 1930L, 1940L, 1950L, 1960L, 1970L, 1980L, 1990L, 2000L, 
2010L), pop = c(1543L, 10500L, 34555L, 48682L, 66960L, 150174L, 
216261L, 284063L, 302163L, 384575L, 367548L, 361561L, 339337L, 
372242L, 399484L, 390724L)), .Names = c("year", "pop"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-16L))
```

Fitting:

```
## SSlogis() is a "self-starting" logistic
m1 <- nls(pop~SSlogis(year,asym,xmid,scal),
          data=dat)
```

Plotting:

```
par(las=1,bty="l",mar=c(5,6,2,2)+0.1)  ## graphics tweaks
with(dat,plot(pop~year,ylab=""))
## add y-label separately 
mtext("population",side=2,las=0,line=4)
yearvec <- 1860:2010
lines(yearvec,predict(m1,newdata=data.frame(year=yearvec)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, the main window says there is an error in init_abline because plot.new has not been called yet. 

Also, if the logistic's model is not the appropriate model to use, which model would you suggest using to model population growth/decay/fluctuation? I'm looking for a more accurate fit than just linear...

Comment: Did you run the `plot` command above?  What kind of a model you should use for population growth (exponential, logistic, etc.) depends on a lot of factors.  You may be looking for the `SSlogis()` and `nls()` functions ... please re-read the bit above about **reproducible** examples ...

Comment: @H3lue , I saw your questions in the Stack Overflow/R chat room from yesterday. If the answer I provided above is not clear to you, you are welcome to comment here, or edit your question to provide more information.